# Form.Control as="select"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a project with more components and I have a table with  that appears by clicking on a button, I make some selections and make the table to disappear and reappear but I doesn't keep the selected values.

Can I make the "form.control" to keep my selected item ?

Here is the code from the table.

```
<Table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Provide or not</th>
                        <th>Link where to find it</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HASI</td>
                        <td>
                            <Form.Control as="select">
                                <option>Provided_by_prj</option>
                                <option>Use_internal</option>
                            </Form.Control>
                        </td>
                        <td><FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" /></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: have you tried any of the suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

In React.js you can use hooks. On that you are looking for is the `useState`.
here I added `selectedValues` whose value you can use for conditionally showing the component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState("");
  return (<Table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Provide or not</th>
        <th>Link where to find it</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>HASI</td>
        <td>
          <Form.Control 
            as="select" 
            value={selectedValues}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedValues(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="Provided_by_prj">Provided_by_prj</option>
            <option value="Use_internal">Use_internal</option>
          </Form.Control>
        </td>
        <td><FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>

  </Table>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force set your values, reactjs should be doing this for you... Maybe there's a problem elsewhere too.

```
<option value={option.value} selected={optionsState == option.value}>{option.label}</option>
```

or something in the like of

```
<Form.Control as="select" value={optionsState}>
  <option value=1>Provided_by_prj</option>
  <option value=2>Use_internal</option>
</Form.Control>
```

See [React JSX: selecting "selected" on selected <select> option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option)