# select value in JS that returns previous value selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **select** in React and just want to console.log value selected.
My problem is that console.log returns the last value selected.
For example if I Select 4, then 3, then 5 the code will render 1 (default value), then 4, then 3.

This is my JSX code:

```
<p>choose Number</p>                                     
<select value={this.state.value} onClick={this.handleNumber}>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
  <option value="four">4</option>
</select>
```

and this the function that handles input change:

```
handleNumber = (event) => {
  this.setState({
     nb: event.target.value
  })
  var number = this.state.nb;
  console.log(number);
}
```

Comment: When do you want to to console the value after the change ? and also you have set the wrong value in the select tag. It should be this.state.nb @droledenom

Comment: Check here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option)

Comment: setState is asynchronous, probably when you are using `console.log()` it hasn't been updatet yet. Try using `this.setState({yourNewState},()=>{console.log(this.state)})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your code.

### Use onChange, not onClick.

Since the event you are handling is a `onClick`, it will never update until the second click.

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleNumber}>
```

### Update the state properly.

In the code you provided, you are giving the select tag this value attribute: `this.state.value`, which is fine if you use `setState()` with the same property of the state.

You are using:

```
this.setState({
  nb: newValue
});
```

This will update `state.nb`, not `state.value`. Use:

```
this.setState({
  value: newValue
});
```

### setState is asynchronous.

This means that React will decide when is the best moment to update the state, which might be later than when you want to use `console.log()`.

Even if you use the `onChange` event, you might not be able to read the state in the next line of code like this:

```
this.setState({
  value: event.target.value
})
console.log(this.state.value)
```

The best approach to do something immediately after state changes, is the setState callback function:

```
this.setState({
  value: event.target.value
},function(){
  console.log(this.state.value)
})
```

And finally, your component with its respective corrections should look something like this:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: "0"
    }
    handleNumber = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.value)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
       <div>
        <p>choose Number</p>                                     
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleNumber}>
          <option value="one">1</option>
          <option value="two">2</option>
          <option value="three">3</option>
          <option value="four">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If you want to test it out, you can check [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/fvpozmtj/).