# select method to restore to default value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Iam trying to do something that look easy but i cant find any soulotion,

i have `<select>` tag with 5 `<option>` all i want to do is when i click a button (have function inside of it) the `select` tag will be the default one (the first one)
for example :

```
            <select className={'smallSelect'} onChange={appliances}>

                 <option defaultValue =''>Add</option>   {/* The default  */}
                 <option  value='<Fan/>'>Air-Conditioner</option>
                 <option value='<HotTub/>'>boilermaker</option>
                 <option value='<Bulb/>'>lamp</option>
                 <option value='<Radio/>'>stereo system</option>

            </select><br/>   {/* After clicking the button the option will be the default */}
            <button className={'myButton'} onClick={newAppliances}>Add</button>
```

Comment: use the selected attribute instead of defaultValue

Answer (score 0):

I assume the button `onClick` event calls the function `newAppliances`?

You need to *set* the select value to ''. So add something like this at the end of your `newAppliances` function.

```
document.getElementById('.smallSelect').value = '';
```

See this:
[How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

### For React

The above solution is for normal javascript, if you want to do the react way, read this:
[React JSX: selecting "selected" on selected <select> option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option)