# How to update parent state and child components props at once (at the same time)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm new to React and basically I'm trying to update a parent `App.js` components' state and its child components (`Team.js` and `Player.js`) props at once. Currently only the parent components' state is being updated. I will try to explain it better with a step by step.

Here I have a parent component `App.js`

```
export default function App() {
      const teams = [
        {
          Name: "Chicago Bulls",
          Players: ["Michael Jordan", "Dennis Rodman", "Scottie Pippen"],
          Championships: 6
        },
        {
          Name: "Golden State Warriors",
          Players: ["Stephen Curry", "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green"],
          Championships: 5
        },
        {
          Name: "Los Angeles Lakers",
          Players: ["Kobe Bryant", "LeBron James", "Magic Johnson"],
          Championships: 17
        }
      ];
      const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState({});
    
      const players = [
        { Name: "LeBron James", MVPs: 4 },
        { Name: "Michael Jordan", MVPs: 5 },
        { Name: "Stephen Curry", MVPs: "2" }
      ];
      const [selectedPlayer, setSelectedPlayer] = useState({});
    
      const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(false);
      const clickedComponent = useRef(null);
      const [show, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    
      const showModal = () => {
        setShowModal(true);
      };
    
      const hideModal = () => {
        setShowModal(false);
      };
    
      const handleModalContent = (clicked) => {
        switch (clicked) {
          case "Team":
            clickedComponent.current = (
              <Team
                teams={teams}
                selectedTeam={selectedTeam}
                setSelectedTeam={setSelectedTeam}
              />
            );
            break;
          case "Player":
            clickedComponent.current = (
              <Player
                players={players}
                selectedPlayer={selectedPlayer}
                setSelectedPlayer={setSelectedPlayer}
              />
            );
            break;
          default:
            clickedComponent.current = null;
            break;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App" style={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              justifyContent: "center",
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              margin: "40px 0px 0px 0px"
            }}
          >
            <div
              className="table-cell"
              onClick={() => {
                handleModalContent("Team");
                setModalContent(true);
                showModal();
              }}
            >
              <div className="table-cell-text">Click to access Team component</div>
            </div>
            <div
              className="table-cell"
              onClick={() => {
                handleModalContent("Player");
                setModalContent(true);
                showModal();
              }}
            >
              <div className="table-cell-text">
                Click to access Player component
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
            The last selected team was: {selectedTeam.Name}
            <br />
            The last selected player was: {selectedPlayer.Name}
          </h3>
          <Modal show={show} modalClosed={hideModal}>
            {(modalContent && clickedComponent.current) || null}
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This component has two arrays of objects (`teams` and `players`) that is sent to `Team` and `Player` components, respectively, as props. `Team` also receives `selectedTeam` and `setSelectedTeam` as props. `Player` receives `selectedPlayer` and `setSelectedPlayer`. Both components have a `Modal` component and a select input. In the `Team` component, the user will select a team and them it will be displayed the selected teams' players, while in the `Player` component a player will be select and them it will be displayed the amount of MVP of the selected player.

`Team.js`

```
const Team = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "0 auto", width: "10em" }}>
      <h3>Select a team</h3>
      <div className="input-group col">
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e === "") props.setSelectedTeam({});
            else {
              let foundTeam = props.teams.find(
                (team) => team.Name === e.target.value
              );
              props.setSelectedTeam(foundTeam);
            }
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a team...</option>
          {props.teams.map((team) => (
            <option key={team.Name} value={team.Name}>
              {team.Name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      {Object.keys(props.selectedTeam).length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h3>{props.selectedTeam.Name} players: </h3>
          <br />
          {props.selectedTeam.Players.map((player, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{player}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Team;
```

`Player.js`

```
const Player = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "0 auto", width: "10em" }}>
      <h3>Select a player</h3>
      <div className="input-group col">
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e === "") props.setSelectedPlayer({});
            else {
              let foundPlayer = props.players.find(
                (player) => player.Name === e.target.value
              );
              props.setSelectedPlayer(foundPlayer);
            }
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a player...</option>
          {props.players.map((player) => (
            <option key={player.Name} value={player.Name}>
              {player.Name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      {Object.keys(props.selectedPlayer).length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h3>
            {props.selectedPlayer.Name} MVPs: {props.selectedPlayer.MVPs}
          </h3>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

So my problem is, if I select an option in the child components, they don't receive the updated selected option (I mean `selectedTeam` for `Team` component and `selectedPlayer` for `Player` component) immediatelly but in the father component `App` I have them updated. So, if I want them to get updated, I need to select an option, close the modal and reopen them again.

For example, here I have `App.js` visual:

[image]

If I open `Team.js` and select a team, I have `selectedTeam` updated in `App.js` but not in `Team.js`:

[image]

So, if I close the modal and reopen `Team` component again, then I have `props.selectedTeam` updated. So I have the following:

[image]

I have the same problem with `Player` component, but in this case regarding `props.selectedPlayer`

How can I make it work properly, I mean, how can I have `props.selectedTeam` and `props.selectedPlayer` updated at once in `App` such as in `Team` and `Player`, respectively? Thank you!

**CodeSandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sun-gs117?file=/src/Team.js:51-1127

Comment: you're not adding `value` to `<select>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option

Comment: @azium I tried it but it didn't solve the problem. Thank you anyways!

Comment: what about `<option selected={player.name === props.selectedPlayer.name}>` in your map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do, I refactored your code and add some comments on that so you know what I did that. one thing to remember is that almost you don't want to store a component in a state.

```
export default function App() {
  const teams = [
    {
      Name: "Chicago Bulls",
      Players: ["Michael Jordan", "Dennis Rodman", "Scottie Pippen"],
      Championships: 6,
    },
    {
      Name: "Golden State Warriors",
      Players: ["Stephen Curry", "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green"],
      Championships: 5,
    },
    {
      Name: "Los Angeles Lakers",
      Players: ["Kobe Bryant", "LeBron James", "Magic Johnson"],
      Championships: 17,
    },
  ];
  const players = [
    { Name: "LeBron James", MVPs: 4 },
    { Name: "Michael Jordan", MVPs: 5 },
    { Name: "Stephen Curry", MVPs: "2" },
  ];

  // This makes typo mistake less and will give you auto complete option
  const componentType = {
    team: "Team",
    player: "Player",
  };

  const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState({});
  const [selectedPlayer, setSelectedPlayer] = useState({});
  // the modalContent state and show state are doing the same thing so one of them is unneccessary
  const [show, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [clickedComponent, setClickedComponent] = useState("");

  const showModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const handleModalContent = (clicked) => {
    setClickedComponent(clicked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          margin: "40px 0px 0px 0px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="table-cell"
          onClick={() => {
            handleModalContent(componentType.team);
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          <div className="table-cell-text">Click to access Team component</div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="table-cell"
          onClick={() => {
            handleModalContent(componentType.player);
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          <div className="table-cell-text">
            Click to access Player component
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
        The last selected team was: {selectedTeam.Name}
        <br />
        The last selected player was: {selectedPlayer.Name}
      </h3>
      <Modal show={show} modalClosed={hideModal}>
        {clickedComponent === componentType.player ? (
          <Player
            players={players}
            selectedPlayer={selectedPlayer}
            setSelectedPlayer={setSelectedPlayer}
          />
        ) : clickedComponent === componentType.team ? (
          <Team
            teams={teams}
            selectedTeam={selectedTeam}
            setSelectedTeam={setSelectedTeam}
          />
        ) : null}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I know how is to just use Hooks `useState` and `useEffect` and just update that state on select change.

Hope the below example for `Player` helps (worked in your code sandbox unless I am not answering your question):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Player = (props) => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props:", props);
    setTest(props.selectedPlayer);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "0 auto", width: "10em" }}>
      <h3>Select a player</h3>
      <div className="input-group col">
        <select
          value={props.selectedPlayer}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e === "") props.setSelectedPlayer({});
            else {
              let foundPlayer = props.players.find(
                (player) => player.Name === e.target.value
              );
              props.setSelectedPlayer(foundPlayer);
              setTest(foundPlayer);
            }
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a player...</option>
          {props.players.map((player) => (
            <option key={player.Name} value={player.Name}>
              {player.Name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>

      <h3>{test.Name} MVPs: {test.MVPs}</h3>
      {/* {Object.keys(props.selectedPlayer).length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h3>
            {props.selectedPlayer.Name} MVPs: {props.selectedPlayer.MVPs}
          </h3>
        </div>
      ) : null} */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```