# How to add attribute selected to select React?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
  return(
    <option value={category._id} key={index}>{category.name}</option>
  )
})}
```

This code display all categories. And I have `const product`

How to make if `product.category == category._id` add attribute selected to select( in map function )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selected={product.category == category._id}` but it's not recommended, you should use the `value` attribute in the `select` tag. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21736116/9124424)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should resolve your issue. I have applied the condition as per your requirement inside the map function.

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
  return(
    product.category == category._id ? <option value={category._id} key={index} selected>{category.name}</option>: <option value={category._id} key={index}>{category.name}</option> 
  )
})}
```