# React JSX: selecting “selected” on selected <select> option with default option have issues

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know, there is one related question at [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option)

- But I'm facing issues with setting `defaultValue`.
- `value` with `onChange` works
- Even with `defaultValue="m"` or `defaultValue="f"` also works
- But while setting defaultValue dynamically is not working.

```js
// value of member.gender is 'f' and confirmed from console.log
<div className="col-3">
  <select name="gender" id="id_gender" defaultValue={member.gender}>
    <option value="m" >Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

- value of `member.gender` is `"f"` but always `Male` i.e. first option gets selected.
- tried to quote {member.geder} using `"${member.gender}"` enclosed in ticks not working.
- I'm using `useRef` based approach, to let form behave as an uncontrolled component. Therefore need to provide defaultValue to select element.

Comment: If it's an **uncontrolled component**, then you don't need to provide a defaultValue. DOM handles it. That's why we called it **uncontrolled components**.

Comment: When you select a different option, DOM updates the UI of `select` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining `defaultValue` or `selected` on each option, you can write `value={member.gender}` on the select tag itself:

```
<div className="col-3">
  <select name="gender" id="id_gender" value={member.gender}>
    <option value="m" >Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question description and comment on another answer, this approach requires me to use `state`  and a function to handle the `onChange` event, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs Library provides two options to handle form elements.

1. **Controlled Components** - If you need to change something in UI according to the form value, use this option.

```js
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    gender: "",
  }; // Step 1 - Create a property related to `select` form element in state object

  onChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(() => ({
      gender: val,
    })); // Step 5 - You can update the value by using `setState` 
  }; // Step 3 - Create a method for `select` form element onChange event

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-3">
        <select
          name="gender"
          id="id_gender"
          value={this.state.gender} {/* Step 2 - Set that `select` related state property to value attribute */}
          onChange={this.onChange} {/* Step 4 - Set that method to onChange event */}
        >
          <option value="m">Male</option>
          <option value="f">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

2. **Uncontrolled Components** - If you just need to form data to save in a database, then you can use this option.

```js
import { Component, createRef } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectEle = createRef(); // Step 1 - Create the reference
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.selectEle.current.value); // Step 3 - You can access to the value like this.
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-3">
        <select name="gender" id="id_gender" ref={this.selectEle}> {/* Step 2 - Add the reference to `select` element */}
          <option value="m">Male</option>
          <option value="f">Female</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But this does not solve the problem at hand. If we use value only, either we need to prove `onChange` or we cannot change the `selected` option at all. I am looking for a way to selected the defaultValue, but you have not given any clue for that.

Comment: These are officially recommended ones. So its better if you can update your code into one of these options.

Comment: I'm following the Uncontrolled Components-based approach. So need to set a default value, as this form is used to update an existing model instance. If I provide `defaultValue="m"` or `defaultValue="f"` it works well. But I need to set the default value dynamically based on the current state of the model instance. There seems to be some issue with JSX expression being used.

Comment: Check my explanations about Controlled & Uncontrolled components. If you want to control the `select` element UI then you have to use **Controlled Components** option. Don't make it complicated by using the wrong option. Always try to follow best practices.

Comment: If you use **Controlled Components** option, you can change `selected` option easily as mentioned above.

Comment: There must be a way to set default value through JSX code. As I can set the same with direct string "f" or "m".